# Module loading order in requirejs

Tags: javascript, requirejs, r.js

We ran into an interesting problem in an existing project,

1. We're using requireJS
2. All our modules are AMD compliant(and we have a lot of them)
3. We need to include a subset of `babel-polyfill` as an AMD module to the project.
4. It's not possible to manually add this dependency to all modules one by one
5. Our code is optimized and bundled using `r.js`

Our main file looks something like this :  // `main.js`

```
require(
[
    'router',
    'someOtherModule', /* In reality we have quite a few more here */
], function(Router, AppModule) {/*... app code ...*/}
)
```

So we'd like to load this `polyfill` module before any other module is loaded in `main.js`

What won't work :

1. Shim - Shim is used for non AMD module.
2. Adding the polyfill to the list above `router` - in the minified code that r.js spits out, there's no guarantee that `polyfill` will actually be in the code before `router`, it's not the defined behavior and thus cannot be counted on.
3. Wrapping everything with another `require['polyfill']` call seems to screw up the r.js optimizer, it won't seem the bundle together the other modules if they're wrapped in `require[]`.
4. Since the `polyfill` is an AMD module, we can't just include it in the `<HEAD>`

Option 3 is still something we're investigating to see if it's possible.

So the question is - Is what we're trying to do possible?

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I load polyfills I always always *always* load them in a `script` element in `head`. I never load them through RequireJS. Loading them through RequireJS gives rise to all kinds of problems, as you discovered. You wrote:

> Since the polyfill is an AMD module, we can't just include it in the `<HEAD>`.

The `babel-polyfill` package [builds itself](https://github.com/babel/babel/blob/f82f8b444acd158f5c453c1f93323b7a4961d319/packages/babel-polyfill/scripts/build-dist.sh) into a script that can be loaded through a `script` element by using Browserify:

```
#!/bin/sh
set -ex

BROWSERIFY_CMD="../../node_modules/browserify/bin/cmd.js"
UGLIFY_CMD="../../node_modules/uglify-js/bin/uglifyjs"

mkdir -p dist

node $BROWSERIFY_CMD lib/index.js \
  --insert-global-vars 'global' \
  --plugin bundle-collapser/plugin \
  --plugin derequire/plugin \
  >dist/polyfill.js
node $UGLIFY_CMD dist/polyfill.js \
  --compress keep_fnames,keep_fargs,warnings=false \
  --mangle keep_fnames \
  >dist/polyfill.min.js
```

If you inspect `dist/polyfill.js`, you'll see it is not an AMD module. (The `define` function it calls is not AMD's `define` function.)

You should be able to adapt this method to your whatever subset of `babel-polyfill` you use.